# Styles from HTML,CSS to GWT world

Tags: css, gwt

I have some code in HTML and CSS where HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="avmenu">
<h2 class="hide">Menu:</h2>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Welcome!</a></li>
```

And my CSS looks like this:

```
#avmenu
{
Style details
}

#avmenu li a:hover
{
Style details
}

a:hover{ Hover styles }
```

So above piece of code shows a menu item and does some animation like color change etc when you hover your mouse over the menu. I have show bare minimum styles sufficient to explain problem at hand.

Now when I migrate this to GWT. We have used `Label` as menu items, and I want to achieve same effect in GWT too. Here is what I have tried

1. I tried to apply CSS Style named "avmenu", this applied basic styles, but of course didn't get animation
2. Then I tried  `DOM.setElementAttribute(orgLbl.getElement(), "id", "avmenu");`  but that also didn't help.

What would be my best option with minimal time and effort to achieve same effect? I can of course listen to events on Label and then change the style, but doing that for all of the widgets would be an overkill!

EDIT- More info: I am building Menu using Label, and adding that to tree

`userMgmtLbl = new Label("User mgmt");
userMgmtLbl.setStyleName(HOME_MENU_LBL_STYLE);
treeItem_1 = configParentTL.addItem(userMgmtLbl);
userMgmtLbl.addClickHandler(Click logic)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the problems that you're running into is that Tree and TreeItem in GWT are composed of arbitrary divs, rather than ul and li as in your original html. (When indoubt you can inspect the DOM of GWT's [showcase](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwTree) to see how the underlying widgets are created).

What this means is that your selectors, such as "#avmenu li a:hover" will no longer work.

If your navigation menu is static, your best bet is probably to use GWT [ui-binders](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html), which are basically gwts templating system. If you use a HTMLPanel as your root widget, you can effectively use all your original HTML verbatim and not worry about trying to mash all the DOM elements into corresponding widgets.

A basic widget would look something like this:

**NavigationWidget.java**
    public final class YourWidget extends Composite {

```
  YourWidget() {
    initWidget(binder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }

  private static final Binder binder = GWT.create(Binder.class);
  interface Binder extends UiBinder<Widget, YourWidget> {}
}
```

**NavigationWidget.ui.xml**

```
<ui:UiBinder
   xmlns:gwt="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
   xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder">

  <gwt:HTMLPanel>
    <div id="avmenu">
      <h2 class="hide">Menu:</h2>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Welcome!</a></li>
    </div>
  </gwt:HTMLPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

As an aside, in this example HTMLPanel adds a DIV of its own to the DOM, making the second div a bit redundant. Unfortunately, widgets in gwt don't have an easy way of setting the ID attribute from templates, so you're stuck with the second div unless you want to switch your #avmenu selector to .avmenu

Answer (score 1):

Post how you are building menu in GWT. You are probably not using anchors inside your labels so your :hover styles are obviously not working.

Comment: My menus are essentially "Label", which are being added to "TreeItem"

Comment: I added the info in original question at emd

Comment: Well that's your answer then. Your styles are not being applied because there are no <a> tags in your labels. You need to rework your styles or insert Anchors into Labels

Comment: Thanks for your pointer Strelok, could you could provide pointers/details on what rework would be needed on CSS/Label Anchor?